# Julia: Macro threads and parallel

Tags: multithreading, julia

as we know, Julia supports parallelism and this is something rooted in the language which is very good.

I recently saw that Julia supports threads but it seems to me to be experimental. I noticed that in the case of using the `Threads.@Threads` macro there is no need for Shared Arrays which is perhaps a computational advantage since no copies of the objects are performed. I also saw that there is the advantage of not declaring all functions with `@everywhere`.

Can anyone tell me the advantage of using the `@parallel` macro instead of the `@threads` macro?

Below are two simple examples of using non-synchronized macros for parallelism.

**Using the @threads macro**

```
addprocs(Sys.CPU_CORES)

function f1(b)
   b+1 
end

function f2(c)
   f1(c)
end

result = Vector(10)

@time Threads.@threads for i = 1:10
  result[i] = f2(i)
end
```

*0.015273 seconds (6.42 k allocations: 340.874 KiB)*

**Using the @parallel macro**

```
addprocs(Sys.CPU_CORES)

@everywhere function f1(b)
   b+1 
end

@everywhere function f2(c)
   f1(c)
end

result = SharedArray{Float64}(10)
@time @parallel for i = 1:10
    result[i] = f2(i)
end
```

*0.060588 seconds (68.66 k allocations: 3.625 MiB)*

It seems to me that for Monte Carlo simulations where loops are mathematically independent and there is a need for a lot of computational performance the use of the `@threads` macro is more convenient. What do you think the advantages and disadvantages of using each of the macros?

Best regards.

Comment: Apart from the comparison (see my answer) the problem with your code is that you use `@time` macro which calculates compilation time. As noted in my answer - it is to be expected that using `@parallel` is slow the first time you use it as Julia spawns the processes. Also most likely your `@threads` example is incorrect as `addprocs(Sys.CPU_CORES)` has no effect in threading. You have to specify environment variable `JULIA_NUM_THREADS` before starting Julia for the code to properly run using multithreading. use `Threads.nthreads()` to check how many threads you have.

Comment: Thank you for the information. From the second time the code runs it seems to me that the time decreases. The right thing would be to mark the time inside the code. Best regards.

Comment: Is there a macro that counts the time of a function by eliminating compile time?

Comment: Typically you should use BenchmarkTools package but the simplest approach is to run the `@time ...` second time - you will get the timings without precompilation overhead (but execution time can vary a bit due to different reasons - e.g. garbage collection- that is why BenchmarkTools was created). But second run of `@time` is good enough to get a general feeling of performance if you do not need a very precise benchmark from my experience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my experience:

#### Threads

Pros:

- shared memory
- low cost of spawning Julia with many threads

Cons:

- constrained to a single machine
- number of threads must be specified at Julia start
- possible problems with false sharing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing)
- often you have to use locking or atomic operations for the program to work correctly; in particular many functions in Julia are not threadsafe so you have to be careful using them
- not guaranteed to stay in the current form past Julia 1.0

#### Processess

Pros:

- better scaling (you can spawn them e.g. on a cluster of multiple machines)
- you can add processes while Julia is running

Cons:

- low efficiency when you have to pass a lot of data between processes
- slower to start
- you have to explicitly share code and data to/between workers

#### Summary

Processes are much easier to work with and scale better. In most situations they give you enough performance. If you have large data transfers between parallel jobs threads will be better but are much more delicate to correctly use and tune.

Comment: Would you know if the following ways of exporting the threads are equivalent?: 1 - export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4; 2 - export JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4.

When doing this is it necessary to compile the code using the -p 4 flag?

Best regards.

Comment: See https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/environment-variables/#JULIA_NUM_THREADS-1. You should use `export JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4` (if you are under `bash`). Under Windows `cmd` use `set` instead. The `-p 4` flag is not needed (it is for multi-processing not for multi-threading). Also I recommend you to read https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing/#Setup-1.

Comment: Does `SharedArray` copy data among processes? Don't different julia processes access the same array?

Comment: Citing JuliaDocs: "A `SharedArray` is a good choice when you want to have a large amount of data jointly accessible to two or more processes on the same machine." In general when you use processes you are not limited to a single machine. Additionally even if you use `SharedArray` there can be overhead of traffic among the workers. See for example the difference in implementation of `advection_parallel!` and `advection_shared!` in https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing/#man-shared-arrays-1 section of the manual.

Comment: Dear, thank you for the information. I'm studying Julia for a week and I'm enjoying the language a lot. Julia is addictive.